# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on domain bought in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I bought a domain through Route 53, oproponitis.com, I have an elastic beanstalk enviroment that works fine, I can open the page through the EBS url. I have a hosted zone where with A record simple record redirecting to this environment, but when I open the page it gives me DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, it drives me crazy as I cant find info about it anywhere, and it is a pretty simple setup.

[image]

Any idea what is maybe going wrong?

#### update

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as a result of a DNS lookup failing for your Name Servers.

As you purchased your domain in Route 53 and also have a public hosted zone in Route 53 this should be an easy solution to fix.

In the AWS console access your public hosted zone and make a note of the values of the `NS` record (there should be 4 domains).

Then in the Route 53 console do the following:

- Access the `Registered Domains` link.
- Click on your domain
- Click `Add or edit Name Servers`
- Specify the values of each of the values you copied earlier from the `NS` record.

Comment: hi Chris, I dont thing that this is the problem, they are the same, see update

Comment: thx a lot, I created a new hosted zone and followed what you said and it worked, thx.

Comment: Glad I could help @AvraamMavridis :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I didn't verify my email.